# Perl reusing parts of regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regex in perl to match this line

```
    PTTO/ETTO/PROO State  NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA     

Here "PTTO/ETTO/PROO State " is constant and line must start with that after that there could be PO,EO,PRO followed by whitespace. Then the same pattern of any one of PO,EO,PRO followed by whitespace repeats.
```

I am trying to match this line with this regex and it matches

```
PTTO/ETTO/PROO State  NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+
```

but it is not matching with the below regex.

```
PTTO/ETTO/PROO State  (NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+){14}
```

Can someone please explain me where am I going wrong here?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: No it should be either NA,PO,EO,PRO followed by whitespace.

Comment: PTTO/ETTO/PROO State ((?:NA|PO|EO|PRO)\s+){14} works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect, this:

```
(NA|PO|EO|PRO\s+){14}
```

Allows `NA`, `PO`, `EO`, or `PRO` + one or more white spaces, 14 times (https://regex101.com/r/rEc16C/3). What you want though is:

```
((?:NA|PO|EO|PRO)\s+){14}
```

Which allows `NA`, `PO`, `EO`, or `PRO`, and one or more white spaces 14 times (https://regex101.com/r/rEc16C/2).

Comment: Is it worth setting the inner bracket to capturing, so you're not capturing the whitespace?

Comment: @Sobrique I'm not sure I know what you mean. I can't see a way to do it with 1 group. I guess neither group needs to be capturing, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the short answer is - I wouldn't try to do this with a regex.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

while (<>) {

   next unless m{^PTTO/ETTO/PROO State};
   my ( undef, undef, @stuff ) = split;
   print Dumper \@stuff;

   my @invalid = grep { not m/^(?:NA|PO|EO|PRO)$/ } @stuff;
   if (@invalid) {
      print "Invalid values: @invalid\n";
   }
   else {
      print "Line matches\n";
   }
}
```

This way you split the line into fields first, then check each of them individually against a regex.